# how to convert JSONObject to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

```
JSONObject user_values = new JSONObject(json.getString("quotes_cat"));
JSONArray user_subject = new JSONArray(
json.getString("quotes_cat"));
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < user_subject.length(); i++)
{
     list.add(user_subject.getString(i));
}
String[] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

The problem is

> type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

JSON output is this

```
{"status":"ok","response":"Fetched Successfully!","quotes_cat":["Life","Love","Success","Happiness","Funny","Love","Success","Happiness","Funny"]}
```

Comment: your json is ok, then what's the issue, why r you converting?

Comment: Why `JSONObject user_values = new JSONObject(
                            json.getString("quotes_cat"));` line?

Comment: i want to put all the values of quotes_cat in to an String[] stringArray

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
JSONObject user_values = new JSONObject(
                            json.getString("quotes_cat"));
```

with this:

```
JSONObject user_values = new JSONObject(json);
```

You need to parse the original JSON String into an JSONObject Java object this way. After that, replace this:

```
JSONArray user_subject = new JSONArray(
                            json.getString("quotes_cat"));
```

with this:

```
JSONArray user_subject = user_values.getJSONArray("quotes_cat"));
```

to get the array out of the newly created root JSONObject :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `quotes_cat` is jsonArray, so try this:

```
        JSONArray user_subject = new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("quotes_cat");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < user_subject.length(); i++)
        {
            list.add(user_subject.getString(i));
        }
        String[] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

When `json` is your json string:

```
String json = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"response\":\"Fetched Successfully!\",\"quotes_cat\":[\"Life\",\"Love\",\"Success\",\"Happiness\",\"Funny\",\"Love\",\"Success\",\"Happiness\",\"Funny\"]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `json` class is `JSONObject`, I suggest you to use `getJSONArray("quotescat")` to retrieve your array.